# Booting large ISO through PXE

Tags: pxe-boot

I currently have a FOG server (which works perfectly fine) and I'm trying to boot Windows 7 through it (with `memdisk`).

But, since the ISO is rather large (more than 6 GB) it will try to put the ISO into memory and then boot however it crashes with the error message `not enough memory to load specified image`. The systems here don't have 6 GB of RAM so I need another way to boot it. I am aware of WDS and SCCM, however I want todo this with FOG.

Is there any way to boot the ISO and install Windows through FOG?

Comment: Why are you trying to force the round peg through the square hole (using FOG for something it's not intended, and with good reason, because there are free tools from MS that do it better anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Microsoft supports this. There is another way.

- you set up a WINPE PXE environment according to this http://www.itblog.ch/2009/09/unattended-windows-7-installation-part-1-creating-a-bootable-winpe-environement/
- now you have a working windows boot environment
- you make the install sets available via a file share and you are ready to go

Comment: Something broke on author's, Nino Stübi's, Wordpress installation, so the link is broken. For anyone needing to access the text of the article, Internet Wayback Machine comes to the rescue: http://web.archive.org/web/20100816072446/http://www.itblog.ch/2009/09/unattended-windows-7-installation-part-1-creating-a-bootable-winpe-environement/